# What is the word for someone who is hard working

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I mean like someone who is very driven and even when working together who always push someone and pays more attention to whatever they do and never give up untill they get what they want.

Comment: There are many words that'll fit that description. You'll need to provide an example sentence, which is the rule here for word requests. Extra details will be helpful, such as whether you're looking for an formal or informal word.

Comment: Better stick to what you said in the title.

Comment: How about "hard-working" (does a hyphen make it one word)?

Answer (score 1):

The word you're looking for could be ambitious:

ambitious: adjective

having or showing a strong desire and determination to succeed.

"a ruthlessly ambitious woman"

synonyms:   aspiring, determined, forceful, pushy, enterprising, pioneering, progressive, eager, motivated, driven, enthusiastic, energetic, zealous, committed, go-ahead, go-getting, purposeful, assertive, aggressive, hungry, power-hungry;

More (of a plan or piece of work) intended to satisfy high aspirations and therefore difficult to achieve.

"an ambitious enterprise"

synonyms:   difficult, exacting, demanding, formidable, challenging, hard, arduous, onerous, tough, stiff, strenuous; bold, grandiose, extravagant, monumental; informal killing, hellish; informal knackering; archaic toilsome
"an ambitious task"